# Difference between Clausius-Clapeyron and Van't Hoff equation

Tags: thermodynamics

I was wondering what is the difference between the Clausius-Clapeyron equation and the Van't Hoff equation.  They appear to have the exact same physical meaning and are often used interchangeably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're two forms of the same equation, but Clausius-Clapeyron uses vapor pressure ($p^*$) where Van 't Hoff uses the reaction equilibrium constant ($K$).

Why does this work out? Well, think of vaporization as a chemical reaction:

$$ \text{X} (l) \longrightarrow \text{X} (\text{g}) $$

The equilibrium constant is defined in terms of [activity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_%28chemistry%29) (*a*):

$$ K=\left.\frac{a_\text{X(g)}}{a_{\text{X}(l)}}\right|_\text{equil} $$

For an ideal liquid solution at modest pressure, *a* is just the mole fraction *x*. And for an ideal gas, *a* is just its partial pressure in bar:

$$ K=\left.\frac px\,\right|_\text{equil}$$

One equilibrium condition is $x=1\ $ and $p=p^*,\ $ so...

$$ K=p^* $$

Or $p^*$ **is the equilibrium coefficient for vaporization**. Now since *K* is characteristic of a reaction at a given temperature, this would imply that if we change *x*, then the new partial pressure at equilibrium would change according to

$$ K=p^*=\frac{p}{x} \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad p=xp^*$$

And that's exactly what happens. Neat, huh?

Comment: Please, take care of the units! K and a are dimensionless, which is correct, but p is [bar] and x is also dimensionless, so K = p/x can't be true in this form. Instead of p, the molar fraction of X in the gas phase, pX/ptotal should be used. Why is x=1 a requirement for equilibrium? Can't mixtures be in equilibrium?